# Optimize the code

Tags: python

I am new to python. I would like all the python gurus to suggest some ways to make the following code more pythonic and hence more efficient .
Its a simple code to find the edit distance between two words.

P.S. I would like improvements in code, not in the logic or algorithm optimization.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,a,b,I=1,D=1,R=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.mem = dict()
        self.la = len(a)
        self.lb = len(b)
        self.I = I
        self.D = D
        self.R = R

    def diff(self,i=0,j=0):
        T = self.diff
        memo = self.mem
        if j == self.lb: return self.D * i
        if i == self.la: return self.D * j
        if (i,j) in memo:
            return memo[(i,j)]
        if self.a[i] == self.b[j]:
            memo[(i,j)] = T( i+1,j+1 )
            return memo[ (i,j) ]
        memo[(i,j)] = min(self.R + T(i+1,j+1) , self.D + T(i+1,j) , self.I + T(i,j+1) ,
         self.D + T(i,j+1) , self.I + T(i+1,j) )
        return memo[(i,j)]
```

Variable explanation:

a,b are two string whose [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) is to be found.
I,D,R Insertion Deletion and Replace cost of a single letter.
mem is dictionary used to memoize the recursive calls.
i and j are the pointers of the string a and b respectively

Comment: Is it all working? Maybe for codereview.SE?

Comment: Its perfectly working. I just want to make it more 'pythonic' since I am learning python now.

Comment: is `def()` supposed to be an instance method? If so, it's not indented right. If not, using `self` as the first parameter is... odd.

Comment: Step 1: Give your variables meaningful names. Or at least document what the variables mean.

Comment: Variable names longer than one letter would be helpful in trying to figure out what you're trying to do...

Comment: The first thing I would recommended you though, it to choose better variable names, using "a","b", "c" for everything makes code really hard to understand by others...

Comment: You want it to be faster, but you don't want to hear about algorithmic improvements? That's just plain wrong thinking.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I am an algorithm student.I know the algorithm improvements :). I just want to make it better to learn the language better.

Comment: Check out these 3 python implementations: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Python

Comment: Another implementation: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576874-levenshtein-distance/

Comment: This code doesn't need a class.  Just group the functions you need in a module.

Comment: At situation would you recommend a class?

Comment: Don't explain the variables, give them names that need no explanation. If you don't like typing get a decent text editor with autocomplete.

Comment: Another nit is one-line if's.  Personally when I see those, I think of Perl's trailing if's.  At least be consistent about it, you have two one-liners followed by a (IMO) properly indented single statement if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pythonic would be:

1. Write lots of unit tests.
2. Don't reinvent the wheel: search online for previous solutions to the problem. See the comments.
3. Don't optimise prematurely: profile your code to work out whether this really is
    a bottleneck and if it is improve the algorithm.
4. Meaningful variable names
5. Don't start local variable names with capital letters
6. Use normal whitespace inside parentheses `T(i+1, j+1)` not `T( i+1,j+1 )`
7. Don't use spurious parentheses round tuples: `memo[i,j]` not `memo[(i,j)]`
8. Don't optimise prematurely: `self.diff(i+1, j+1)` not `T(i+1,j+1)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is quite pythonic, but as stated in the comments, it is a very bad idea to choose generic single letter variable words, and renders your code very hard to understand, and that is not pythonic.

This applies to every programming language, but in some cases even more so in python and other [dynamically typed languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_type#Dynamic_typing).

Try to be really generous and descriptive with variable names.

See the [example](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/02/about-me.html) (under "What is the meaning of 'Coding Horror'?") in *this* site creators blog.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider factoring the memoization layer out of your class, along the lines of [this decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).